# Javascript / Clipboard API / Safari iOS / NotAllowedError Message

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, clipboard

I have a short Problem. I want to add a text to the clipboard on my iOS Device when I press a Button which use a ajax request to get the data into the clipboard.

With the Browser on my Desktop and my Android device it works very well but with my iOS Device a get an issue.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "missing_string.php",
            data: getAttributes($(this)),
            success: function(data) {
                if (navigator.clipboard) {
                    navigator.clipboard.writeText(data)
                        .then(() => {
                            alert("SUCCESS");
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            alert(err);
                            console.log('Something went wrong', err);
                        });
```

So I get following error message:

> NotAllowedError: the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

How can I get my Text to the clipboard? I use iOS 13.5 and 13.4 should support the Clipboard API.

Answer (score 19):

https://webkit.org/blog/10247/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13-1/

```
Async Clipboard API
WebKit brings the Async Clipboard API to this release of Safari...

you should read it
```

TLDR:
The implementation is available through the `navigator.clipboard` API which must be called within user events

You are trying to copy to the clipboard as a result of an API call instead of in the context of a user interaction.  This is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem now too and Jordan's answer was helpful. I did seem to find a workaround though, using `setTimeout`.

For example:

```js
const resultText = await getResultText()
setTimeout(() => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(resultText)
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was not running the web app in a "safe context" (HTTPS). Try `window.isSecureContext` in console.

Also, to save you hours of trial and error, iOS blocks pasting from other websites and apps, for some reason. Even though it asks for permission to paste, it doesn't. Just try the demo here on an iPhone: https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#demos
:(