# Clipboard API used in conjunction with Axios in click event

Tags: javascript, safari, axios, html5-clipboard-api

### TL;DR

Is it possible to get the Clipboard API to write text from the result of an Axios get request in Safari even when the `writeText()` is a direct result of a user event?

---

### Long version

I have an async button click event and inside of that click event I'm using Axios to fetch the HTML of another page. I want to take that string and save it to the clipboard using the Clipboard API.

This works in Chrome and Firefox but there are some issues in Safari I will show below.

Testing in:

- Chrome 88.0.4324.192
- Firefox 78.7.1
- Safari 14.0.3

Closest SO issue I could find relating to this sort of thing is [Javascript / Clipboard API / Safari iOS / NotAllowedError Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327358/javascript-clipboard-api-safari-ios-notallowederror-message) but I feel like my Clipboard API call is called directly within a user event.

---

### Attempt 1 to get to work in Safari

```js
copyButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
  try {
    const {data: html} = await axios.get('https://website-to-copy.com');
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(html);
    console.log('copy was a success');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

#### Result 1 in Safari

- Request is successfully made
- Failure to write to clipboard

  - NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

#### My thoughts on Result 1

At the time I was thinking this would work. The `writeText()` call is a direct result of a user event and I'm just passing in a string... even though that string is a result of an Axios get request. When it didn't work I thought there must be something with the get request throwing off the permissions.

---

### Attempt 2 to get to work in Safari

```js
copyButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
  try {
    const {data: html} = await axios.get('https://website-to-copy.com');
    // throw in a random string thinking maybe something
    // in the get request is throwing Clipboard API off
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText('some random text to copy');
    console.log('copy was a success');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

#### Result 2 in Safari

- Request is successfully made
- Failure to write to clipboard

  - NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

#### My thoughts on Result 2

I was really surprised when my random text didn't copy. When attempt #1 failed I decided to leave the get request in but just feed `writeText()` some random text, not related to the get request in anyway, just to see if it would copy. Obviously the get request is still affecting the Clipboard API.

---

### Attempt 3 to get to work in Safari

```js
copyButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
  try {
    // remove get request and see if i can get anything to
    // copy to clipboard
    //const {data: html} = await axios.get('https://website-to-copy.com');
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText('some random text to copy');
    console.log('copy was a success');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

#### Result 3 in Safari

- Text successfully copied to clipboard

#### My thoughts on Result 3

Well I'm happy that I can successfully copy text with the clipboard API in Safari. However I really would like to copy the result of the get request.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? Facing the same issue. Works in other browsers, but not in Safari when it's after another `await`-ed statement.

Comment: Safari does not allow data to be written to clipboard from result of async function

Answer (score 0):

```
copyButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    try {  
        const { ClipboardItem } = window;
        await navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ "text/plain": getUrl() })]).then(()=>console.log("copied"))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
    
const getUrl = () => {
    const {data: html} = await axios.get('https://website-to-copy.com');
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ClipboardItemData'` at "text/plain"

Comment: Are you using typescript in your project?