# Javascript clipboard.readText() not working in IOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).on('focus', function () {
            navigator.clipboard.readText().then(q => {
                alert(q);   
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
            });

         });
    });
```

Run well on Android's browser. But in IOS Safari, nothing happens.
Please help !

Comment: Some changes has been done on webkit: https://webkit.org/blog/10247/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13-1/ Answer has been done here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327358/javascript-clipboard-api-safari-ios-notallowederror-message