# safari clipboard read permission

Tags: javascript, safari, clipboard

How to I change the clipboard permission on Safari (so that we can do `navigator.clipboard.readText()` if the user allows?
On Chrome it is simple, as it is just next to the URL. On FF it's is a bit tricky, but I found a solution. I can't find it for Safari, though. But I believe it is possible from the documentation.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67127262/1270341

Answer (score 0):

There is still no option for clipboard access permissions. Safari supports the Clipboard API since 2020, but it locks it down to only work when triggered by a direct user interaction.

There is a trick for writing that involves creating a `ClipboardItem`.

```js
const text = new ClipboardItem({
  "text/plain": fetch(this.sourceUrlValue)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain" }))
})
navigator.clipboard.write([text])
```

But that is not the case for reading, you will have to create a button and then the `Paste` option will be displayed.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);
});
```

Try it out https://jsfiddle.net/zsyn0kp6/

Hope that helps