# How can I write text to the clipboard in .NET Blazor while being compatible with iOS?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have the following MudBlazor button that copies text from a row inside a table:

```
<MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => WriteTextAsync(@context.TokenName))"></MudIconButton>

@code {
    public ValueTask WriteTextAsync(string text) {
        return JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("copyToClipboard", text);
    }
}
```

This is the JavaScript function inside _Host.cshtml that the button invokes:

```
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).catch((err) => {
            alert(err.message);
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code does work as expected on PC and Android but on iOS the following exception is thrown:

> The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context possibly because the user denied permission.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327358/javascript-clipboard-api-safari-ios-notallowederror-message) thread it was stated that the reason for the exception is that `navigator.clipboard` must be called by user interactions and not by API calls. So it seems that the interaction with the button in Blazor does not count as a user interaction.

At the moment, unfortunately, I have no approach to be able to solve this problem and I am grateful for any help.

EDIT:

I have created a temporary fix by replacing the MudBlazor-button with the following HTML-button:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard(this.id)" id="@context.TokenName">
<svg> /*contains the graphics of the mudblazor button*/ </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: don't have time for a proper answer, but i think that you could add an event listener to the DOM element as it is mounted, and this will be triggered on click, and copy a value that is updated by blazor and shared with your js code. I dont know if it is clear, but it could work. eventually I would isolate this in a dedicated component.

Comment: @EmidioTorre this was my first approach but led to inconsistent behaviour because of race conditions. Check out my edit, this temporarily fixes the problem.