# Cannot copy text to clipboard when is using a promise result with ReactJS

Tags: ios, reactjs, es6-promise, mobile-safari, clipboard

I am using React 18, with iOS 15.6.1 Safari, `navigator.clipboard.writeText` API sended an error:

```
NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const copy = () => {
    fetch("https://api.paugram.com/acgm")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);

        setText(res.title);

        if (navigator.clipboard) {
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(res.title).catch((e) => {
            console.log("Error", e);
          });
        }
      });
  };

  const noPromiseCopy = () => {
    if (navigator.clipboard) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText("Simple text content").catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error", e);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <button onClick={copy}>Copy</button>
      <button onClick={noPromiseCopy}>noPromiseCopy</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Click the "Copy" and "noPromiseCopy" buttons, it works in M1 Mac's Chrome. but in iOS Safari, "Copy" runs failed.

[Reproduction Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-copy-to-clipboard-bug-dkuzdz?file=/src/App.js:379-408)

Why?

I tried to writing this with original JavaScript, it still works in iOS Safari, Is this an react bug?

- Code: [Link](https://github.com/Dreamer-Paul/Code-Snippets/blob/main/2022-12-09%20%E5%89%AA%E8%B4%B4%E6%9D%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95/index.html)
- Demo: [Link](https://dreamer-paul.github.io/Code-Snippets/2022-12-09%20%E5%89%AA%E8%B4%B4%E6%9D%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript / Clipboard API / Safari iOS / NotAllowedError Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327358/javascript-clipboard-api-safari-ios-notallowederror-message)